# Count if having certain figure by matching two columns

Tags: sql-server

TABLE-A

```
EMP_ID  BENEFIT_Per   Yes/No
  A       20    
  A       40    
  A      100    
  B       30    
  B       30    
  C      100    
  C       10    
  C       20    
  D       30    
  D       40    
  D       50
```

TABLE-A (With Answer)

```
EMP_ID  BENEFIT_Per   Yes/No
  A       20            yes
  A       40            yes
  A      100            yes
  B       30            no
  B       30            no
  C      100            yes
  C       10            yes
  C       20            yes
  D       30            no
  D       40            no
  D       50            no
```

How to update (in same table) if employee has taken 100 percent benefit, Yes or No?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am finding for SQL Server

Comment: Same question twice + picture of the same question?

Comment: was not able to present well that's why

Comment: Friends,Please suggest SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

Find the max value from `benefit_per` and if it is 100, update all the columns equal to yes on where the derived queries emp_id and tableA's emp_id match:

```
update tableA
set yes_no = case when max_benefit = 100 then 'yes' else 'no' end
from (select emp_id, max(benefit_per) as max_benefit from tableA group by emp_id) t1
where t1.emp_id = tableA.emp_id
```

[rextester](http://rextester.com/CBJ44401) sample

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (EMP_ID CHAR(1), BENEFIT_Per INT, [Yes/No] NVARCHAR(3) NULL )
INSERT INTO @tab
(EMP_ID, BENEFIT_Per)
SELECT 'A', 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 50

;WITH cteZ
AS(
    SELECT T.EMP_ID
         , MAX(T.BENEFIT_Per) 'MxBen'
    FROM @tab T 
    GROUP BY T.EMP_ID
)
UPDATE T
SET T.[Yes/No] = CASE WHEN Z.MxBen = 100 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM @tab T
LEFT JOIN  cteZ Z ON Z.EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID


Output
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call your original table t1. You want this sub-table first:

```
select EMP_ID, max(BENEFIT_Per) bene_max from t1 group by EMP_ID
```

And then join the original table with this one

```
select t1.EMP_ID, t1.BENEFIT_Per, t2.bene_max = 100 from t1
left join (select EMP_ID, max(BENEFIT_Per) bene_max from t1 group by EMP_ID) t2
on t1.EMP_ID = t2.EMP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  A
SET     A.[Yes/No] = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                                        SELECT TOP 1 1 
                                        FROM [Table] 
                                        WHERE EMP_ID = A.EMP_ID AND BENEFIT_Per = 100
                                    ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM    [Table] A
WHERE   1=1
```